# Setting up programs to startup at login

Tags: startup

Have a new ponder hoping someone can answer. Keep in mind I am very new at linux and Ubuntu 14.04. What I would like to setup is setting certain programs to load at login to my account. I have not found a startup folder or setup options for programs to load at startup. Any Ideas?

Please remember I am very new to linux and Ubuntu desktop. I am still learning my way around and the code for terminal sessions. So please be very descriptive in responses. Thank you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you you say you're very new to `Unix` alike, so I'd give you a simple hint using `GUI` press <kbd>Superkey</kbd> or go directly to `Dash` on Launcher and type: `Startup Applications` launch the appropriate icon. When it's opened looks like this:

[image]

click `Add` then `Browse` and choose the path in a line `command` to an app you'd like to startup, by default they go to `/usr/bin/` for example for `psensor` it be `/usr/bin/psensor` choose and press `Add` you can also name it your way.

Answer (score 0):

I found the startup applications applet in the computer and programs search button in the toolbar. I was able to setup the programs I wanted to startup at login. I am using a laptop that does not have a superkey, so this was the only way I could get to it. Ubuntu 14.04 desktop looks different than the image JohnnyEnglish has posted however his post helped me get to where I needed to. Thanks for the help, bud.

Comment: He doesn't look like he has default Unity desktop