# How to run Thunderbird on startup, minimised?

Tags: thunderbird, session

How can I set Thunderbird to launch automatically in the minimised or hidden-in-Launcher state?

First component of problem is starting it. I do not know which 'Command' is needed.

Second component of problem is keeping it minimised, or hidden from Launcher (given that it's unlocked from Launcher).

Comment: This great solution http://askubuntu.com/a/53658/265974 should work if you replace `firefox` with `thunderbird` and `w.maximize()` with `w.minimize()` and put a .desktop file in your `$HOME/.config/autostart` folder.

Answer (score 1):

To start thunderbird when you log in, add it to the list of start-up applications See [Setting up programs to startup at login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477457/setting-up-programs-to-startup-at-login?rq=1) - in short, open the "Startup Applications" app, and add an entry for Thunderbird.

For starting it minimized, I don't know of any native way, but I use an add-on: [FireTray](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/firetray/?src=userprofile)
It minimizes to the tray, however:

[image: FireTray preferences dialog]

(Please excuse the clipped nature of the bottom - I did a hasty job of cropping out a *lot* of empty space from a too-large picture.)